# Store ProtoBuf object in SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, protocol-buffers

I am meaning to store a `ProtoBuf` object in `SharedPreferences`. `Protocol Buffers` only allow parsing from `ByteString` or `Byte Array`. But `SharedPreferences` support neither. I was wondering if there was a way to do it without having to create another serializable model and mapping to it first.

I Tried this way, but i get `InvalidProtocolBufferException`:

```
public static void setProtoData(ProtoData data) {
    Prefs.putString(Constants.SHARED_PREF_PROTO_DATA, String.valueOf(data.toByteString()));
}

public static ProtoData getProtoData() {
    String str = Prefs.getString(Constants.SHARED_PREF_PROTO_DATA, null);
    ProtoData data = null;

    try {
        data = ProtoData.parseFrom(ByteString.copyFromUtf8(str));
    } catch (InvalidProtocolBufferException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can save a byte array in SharedPreferences by using android.util.Base64.

For saving:

```
String saveThis = Base64.encodeToString(array, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

For loading:

```
byte[] array = Base64.decode(stringFromSharedPrefs, Base64.DEFAULT);
```